# Update-database error - Foreign Key Constraint on table without any foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two tables, `Product` & `ProductCategory`. When I do `add-migration` in the package manager console, everything is ok, but when I run `update-database`, I get an error which is so irrelevant:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductCategories_Products_ProductId' on table 'ProductCategories' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

What is different about this question from others is that my `ProductCategory` table doesn't contain any foreign key.

**ProductCategory.cs**

```
public class ProductCategory : DomainModel<int>
{
    [Required, StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool VisibleToCustomerPublicAccount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool RequireApproval { get; set; }

    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product : DomainModel<int>
{
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductCategoryId")]
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AllowEdit { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SupplierId")]
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(5,2)")]
    public decimal SalesTaxRate { get; set; }

    public int? PressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PressId")]
    public virtual Press Press { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Artwork { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Delivery { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Material { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Finishing { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Proofs { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Packing { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string TermsAndInstructions { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string PrintReadyFile { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool VisibleToCustomerPublicAccount { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowShortDescription { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowItemDescription { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowPriceStartFrom { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowPriceList { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowPriceSubtotalTax { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowPrintReadyFile { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AllowUserToUploadArtworkFile { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfUploadBoxes { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool MakeFirstFileUploadMandatory { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowStock { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowSoldInPacks { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AllowGroupRun { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowCustomerCode { get; set; }

    [Required ,DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowItemCode { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool HidePricesOfOptions { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool QuickAddFunctionEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

I saw many solution on this kind of questions but the solutions don't hold because there is no key on the `ProductCategory` table.

Comment: What does `DomainModel<int>` look like?

Comment: `public abstract class DomainModel<T>
    {
        [Key]
        public T Id { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsInactive { get; set; } = false;

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsTransient
        {
            get
            {
                return Id.Equals(default(T));
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @OJRaqueño when I run "EXEC sp_fkeys 'ProductCategories'"  there is an FK_Name column shows FK_CategoryUsers_ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId
FK_Options_ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId
FK_Products_ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId if that helps

Comment: What happens if you map the navigation property ProductCategory explicitly using fluent api?